# Conteo de celdas con condición

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo esta tabla de Excel, es de proyectos. Tengo un código VBA que genera una hoja donde recopila y analiza algunos datos de la tabla, cuando presionas un botón se genera la hoja nueva. Hasta ahí todo bien, esta es la hoja de datos:

[image: En esta columna tengo el problema]

Ok, hasta ahí todo bien. Ahora, necesito un código que recorra la columna etapa, para contar las filas que contiene entre la celda que dice Etapa, hasta la siguiente celda que dice Etapa, es decir, como aparece en la imagen, en la celda 22 Dice etapa, necesito que cuente desde esa celda hasta la siguiente celda que dice etapa (en este caso la 32) y que ese resultado del conteo me lo ponga en una celda, en este caso en la primera diría 8, en otra celda diría 9, etc.

Tengo un código pero no me funciona bien y no está completo a lo que necesito:

```vb
For i = 1 To 100
        array3(i) = Worksheets("Concentrado").Range("A" & i).Value
        If i = 100 Then
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    'En este código se guardan los valores de la columna en un arreglo
```

```vb
For Each i In array3(i) 
'Recorre el arreglo que almaceno en el arreglo anterior
        If i = "Etapa" Then
'Si encuentra la palabra Etapa entonces que sume la posición para que
'no se detenga en la primer celda Etapa que encontró, si no hasta la siguiente
        i = i + 1
        Do Until i = "Etapa"
'Contar hasta que encuentre la siguiente Etapa y almacenarlo en esa
'posicion de otro array
            array1(1) = i.Count
        Loop
    Next i
```

Comment: Hola, el código que has puesto no tiene nada que ver con lo que pides., solo guarda valores en un array pero no hay ningún intento del conteo que pides. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Listo modifique el codigo, disculpa la tardanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes estimado(a).

La solución que te tengo no se si será la mejor o la más optima pero te servirá.

Genere las respuestas del conteo el la columna B ya que no se donde la necesitas en tu arreglo.

```
Sub Conteo()

Dim UltimaLinea
Dim Conteo

UltimaLinea = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Conteo = 0

For I = 1 To UltimaLinea
    If Range("A" & I) = "ETAPA" Then
    Conteo = 0
    ElseIf Range("A" & I) = "" Then
    Conteo = Conteo
    Else
    Conteo = Conteo + 1
    End If
    Range("B" & I) = Conteo
Next I
End Sub
```

Para explicar un poco, lo que hice fue hacer la variable de UltimaLinea que te encuentra el final de las líneas de la columna A para saber hasta donde tiene que realizarse el FOR, luego donde empieza en mi caso mi I empezaba en 1, y si tenia en la cela la palabra "ETAPA" reinicia mi contador a 0, si no contiene texto (que es lo que sucede con las celdas combinadas como en mi ejemplo A2 y A12) pues que no haga nada con el conteo y por ultimo si es un caso contrario, en otras palabras que tenga números pues que sea conteo +1.

Hoja al inicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hoja luego de la macro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver en la columna B tienes los resultados que querías, ya de ahí ves si lo pones como otra variable para lo que necesites.

Saludos espero te sirva.

JM

Comment: Hola amigo!! Muchísimas gracias!! Creo que tu código me sirve a la perfección amigo, solo una cosa, como podría hacerlo para que solo me muestre en la columna B el resultado del conteo de cada etapa?